# Can't call Web api from Xamarin

Tags: asp.net-web-api, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to make a simple web api call using HttpClient in an iOS build. When setting the client.BaseAddress, the BaseAddress always ends up null. I can't find what could possibly be wrong.

```
    using System.Net.Http;
     ....
    private const string BaseApiUrl = "http://localhost:55904/";
    static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseApiUrl);
    // client.BaseAddress is still null
```

I downloaded a sample non-Xamarin project and the same code works fine.
Any ideas?

**Update**
As I continue messing with this I figured I would try some of the other platforms. UWP seems to work fine. I was going to test Android but all of a sudden, I have a bunch of "The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context" errors.
I'm new to Xamarin but not to VS or C#.

**Update** 
I was just thinking, does iOS need to request any special permission for internet access? If so, where would that be set?

Comment: you need to use the IP or FQDN of your server, not "localhost"

Comment: Ok so that was pretty dumb of me thinking localhost would work while running on another machine. I tried changing it to my local IP http://10.0.0.1:55904/ and it's still null. This may be because I'm running IIS Express. 
I figured it would only connect to the IP when making a Get, Post or some other call, not that the assignment would fail

Comment: IIS Express will not allow connections from remote systems by default.  There are workarounds, try googling.

Comment: I'm trying to configure to allow remote connections. Thanks.

Comment: After hours of fighting with IIS Express I decided to move it to our actual server. I still have the exact same problem as before.
I can use Postman to test the calls to make sure everything is ok.
It must have something to do with Xamarin.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone else comes across this problem, I found the cause. It turns out that the iOS project didn't include a reference to System.Net.Http. Once I added the reference, everything worked fine.